# JSP error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: postgresql, tomcat

I created this jsp file and i am using Tomcat and postgresql. I have created a database in postgresql and want to access that database through jsp. When I run the code I get the error

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1332) org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1181)

I have my jar file in the web-inf/lib .

Here is the jsp

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
This program test connectivity of PostgreSQL from JSP<br>
Contents of students table (created by  create table readers (reader_id integer, reader_f name, reader_l name, date_of_birth date, address text, phone numeric(11), sex character(1)) <br>
id  name<br>
-----------<br>

<%
String connectionURL =
"jdbc:postgresql://cop4710-postgresql.cs.fiu.edu:5099/fall17_smete008?user=fall17_smete008&password=4742244s";

Connection connection = null;
Statement statement = null;
ResultSet rs = null;

%>


<html><body>

<%
Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver").newInstance();
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL);
statement = connection.createStatement();
rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM readers");

while (rs.next()) {
out.println(rs.getString("reader_id")+"<br>");
out.println(rs.getString("reader_f")+"<br>");
}

rs.close();
%>

 <dependency>
    <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
</dependency>
</body></html>
```

Can you please help me figure out what i am getting this error?

Comment: Thank you for editing my question but can you please help me with my question @ a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 0):

Copy your jar driver to Tomcat lib folder and add `<scope>provided</scope>` to maven dependency.
Also it is better not to mix business logic code with frontend implementation.

Comment: im sorry but what is the maven dependency? Im new to JSP and Tomcat

Comment: See in your code: `<dependency>`. This should be in `pom.xml`. If you don't use Maven, just copy jar file to Tomcat lib folder.